# regex pcre delete some text

Tags: css, regex

I try take of two word in this string, the first one and the the end:

```
radius-bottom-left-bgc
radius-bottom-left-l
radius-bottom-left-bgc
radius-bottom-left-l
etc...

I need keep just the middle ?
top-left

$display_prop= preg_replace('/^(\w{6})\-(\w{3,6})\-(\w{4,5})\-(\w{6})$/','$2-$3',   $display_prop);
echo $display_prop.'<br>';
```

my echo display

`radius-top-left-bgc`
`radius-top-right-bgc`
`radius-bottom-right-bgc`
`radius-bottom-left-bgc`
`radius-top-left-l`
`radius-bottom-right-l`

What' wrong with my regex ?
Thanks

Comment: Your last capturing group doesn't match your example..  your last capturing group is `(\w{6})`, but for your example data it should be `(\w{1,3})`. Fix that and it should work.  :)

Comment: Thanks, that just very nice :)
I dont undestand why I didn't see that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last capturing group doesn't match your example..

Your last capturing group is `(\w{6})`, but for your example data it should be `(\w{1,3})`.

Fix that and it should work. :)

Comment: Great!! If this was answer to your question then please select it as answer. Thanks. :)